# Installing Java JDK 6 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty) error message

Tags: java, ubuntu

My machine is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty).

I had multiple Java installed on my Ubuntu machine so I decided to delete all of them according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) and install only Java JDK 6 (which is what I need to compile Android 4.3) using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

but I'm getting the following error message:

```
oracle-java6-installer is already the newest version.
```

**My question:**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like not everything was dispatched utterly, but that's quite alright - the command you'll want is:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java6-installer
```

This will forcibly reinstall the package, without trying to remove it by any other means.